# MySQL 8.0, MacOS, create database issue?

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

when I use: `CREATE DATABASE test;`

> ERROR 3680 (HY000): Failed to create schema directory 'test' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed MySQL properly. Try asking for help in [dba.se]

Answer (score 3):

Run this in the `mysql` client (or similar):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

Then look at the ownership and permissions for that directory. It should be owned by the `mysql` user,  have the `mysql` group, and the `mysql` user should have read, write and execute (rwx) permissions, and I think similar for the group.

Which process is running the mysql daemon? It should be the `mysql` user. In Linux you can get a list of processes which includes the user who is running each. I assume you can do something similar on MacOSX (if that is what you're using).

Assuming this is a new installation, please see this documentation page about [Initializing the data directory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html).